# Will there be the normal GNOME desktop available for download

Tags: gnome

Will we have a GNOME version of Ubuntu available for download like Kubuntu is for KDE and Xubuntu is for Xfce. Maybe something like 'Gubuntu' for GNOME

Comment: It's unclear what this question means by "normal GNOME desktop". Is it asking about the desktop environment or the shell? The former is already included, but the latter could mean Unity, GNOME Shell, GNOME Classic, etc.

Answer (score 4):

"GNOME version of Ubuntu" is not a good definition, since the default Unity variant will also be using GNOME extensively (but not GNOME Shell). Unity and GNOME are not mutually exclusive.

If you mean a non-Unity GNOME version, it won't be "available for download", but on the CD and installed by default, since it will be the fallback for systems that can't run Unity.

Comment: As for the latter point, Ubuntu has had a Unity 2D variant it was using as a fallback for a couple releases now, and in 12.10 it will be removed completely in favor of running Unity 3D on all systems using llvmpipe, which allows the CPU to handle the graphics processing if the GPU can't do it. Currently, neither GNOME Classic nor GNOME Shell come with a standard Ubuntu installation, though both can still be obtained through the Software Center post-install.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently an unofficial community-led GNOME Shell remix of Ubuntu under development called **Gnomebuntu**, which aims to become an officially-recognized variant later on. You can follow developments on the project [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1999827). (There is an [official website](http://gnomebuntu.org/) for it, but as of this writing all it has is a nice-looking placeholder.)

**9/3/2012 UPDATE:** The project is now called **Ubuntu GNOME Remix** after the original name was [blocked by the GNOME project](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/gnome-flavoured-ubuntu-spin-releases-alpha), and an initial alpha version is now available for download [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/ReleaseNotes#Download_the_Alpha).

Comment: I believe that it will be an important distribution in future.